# Common.Logging.NLog not available for net core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, nlog, common.logging

I'm currently using Common.Logging version 3.4.0-beta2 and NLog 5.0.0-beta07 on netcoreapp1.1. (its and ASP Net Core mvc project)
I cannot find Common.Logging.NLog specific version for that case.

In case it is not yet available, which log file option do I have as adapter for net core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally created two classes:

```cs
public class CommonLoggingNLogAdapter : ILoggerFactoryAdapter
{
    public ILog GetLogger(Type type)
    {
        return new NLogAdapter(type);
    }

    public ILog GetLogger(string key)
    {
        return new NLogAdapter(key);
    }
}
```

and

```cs
public class NLogAdapter : ILog
{
    private Logger log;

    public bool IsTraceEnabled { get { return log.IsTraceEnabled; } }

    public bool IsDebugEnabled { get { return log.IsDebugEnabled; } }

    public bool IsErrorEnabled { get { return log.IsErrorEnabled; } }

    public bool IsFatalEnabled { get { return log.IsFatalEnabled; } }

    public bool IsInfoEnabled { get { return log.IsInfoEnabled; } }

    public bool IsWarnEnabled { get { return log.IsWarnEnabled; } }

    public IVariablesContext GlobalVariablesContext => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public IVariablesContext ThreadVariablesContext => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public INestedVariablesContext NestedThreadVariablesContext => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public NLogAdapter(Type type)
    {
        log = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(type.ToString());
    }

    public NLogAdapter(string key)
    {
        log = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(key);
    }

    public void Debug(object message)
    {
        log.Debug(message);
    }

    public void Debug(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Debug(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Debug(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Debug(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Debug(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Debug(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DebugFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DebugFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Error(object message)
    {
        log.Error(message);
    }

    public void Error(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Error(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Error(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Error(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Error(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Error(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Fatal(object message)
    {
        log.Fatal(message);
    }

    public void Fatal(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Fatal(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Fatal(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Fatal(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Fatal(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Fatal(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void FatalFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void FatalFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Info(object message)
    {
        log.Info(message);
    }

    public void Info(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Info(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Info(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Info(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Info(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Info(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void InfoFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void InfoFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Trace(object message)
    {
        log.Trace(message);
    }

    public void Trace(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Trace(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Trace(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Trace(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Trace(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Trace(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void TraceFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void TraceFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void TraceFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void TraceFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Warn(object message)
    {
        log.Warn(message);
    }

    public void Warn(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        log.Warn(exception, message.ToString());
    }

    public void Warn(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Warn(Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Warn(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Warn(IFormatProvider formatProvider, Action<FormatMessageHandler> formatMessageCallback, Exception exception)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WarnFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WarnFormat(IFormatProvider formatProvider, string format, Exception exception, params object[] args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then I can configure NLog as logger by doing:

```cs
Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new CommonLoggingNLogAdapter();
```

This is a temporary solution I'm implementing until there is an official release.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a package for NLog 5 and Common logging currently.

Alternatives are:

- liblog:

  1. just copy [the file liblog.cs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damianh/LibLog/master/src/LibLog/LibLog.cs), see [website](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog)
  2. Manually rename the namespace YourRootNamespace to your project's root namespace.
  3. Enable LIBLOG_PORTABLE compiler directive.
- Or use Microsoft's logging abstraction. See [docs how to log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging)
  and install [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore), and check [install instructions](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(csproj---vs2017))

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm trying to use a library that internally uses Common.Logging, so I will test your first alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can find a custom build nuget-package here (Common.Logging.NLog45):

https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/pull/176

Supports NetCore and structured logging.